# Как найти расстояние между телефоном и объектом в камере, используя пиксели ?

Tags: android, камера, android-camera

Как найти расстояние между телефоном и объектом в камере, используя пиксели ?

Comment: Пиксели? Вам ещё придётся использовать числа, переменные и наверное классы.

Comment: Не очень понял что Вы имеете в виду

Comment: Пиксели не содержат нужной вам информации. Это просто значения цвета на фотоматрице, ничего больше.

Comment: Да, но если имеется количество пикселей до объекта, количество пикселей до конца экрана и расстояние которое соответствует например 10 000 пикселям, то думаю можно найти и расстояние до объекта.

Comment: Мой вопрос в том как найти расстояние в пикселях от нижней части камеры до объекта

Comment: На фото нет «количества пикселей до объекта», что бы это не значило. Если вы фотографируете сплошную зелёную стену, у вас получаются просто все зелёные пиксели вне зависимости от расстояния. Информации о расстоянии до объектов на фото нет.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/108212/ вперёд и с песней. Выделяете объекты на изображении, а потом считайте пиксели с любой стороны. Но если вы задали такой вопрос, то вы ничего не понимаете в данной теме и своими силами вам этот вопрос не решить

Comment: Мне нужно не с изображения а с камеры. То есть пользователь направил камеру на сторону какого либо объекта, а не сфотографировал его.